# Is there a Linux command or a script that I could write and run on linux to call a Windows DOS command prompt? If so, how?

Tags: linux, batch-file, cmd, call, prompt

I would like to automate an existing process that involves executing programs on a Linux server which would then send output file(s) to be edited by excel. The resulting .csv files must be run on a Windows DOS command prompt. If I would like to automate this process, one of the things that I would like to know is if it's possible for me to write and run a script on a Linux server to call a Windows DOS command prompt. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you install Cygwin (https://www.cygwin.com/), it provides an SSH server for Windows. Once installed and configured, you can access it like any other SSH server.
In the Cygwin SSH server, you can execute both Cygwin compiled programs and Windows native programs (Windows native programs will show the GUI on the users desktop, even though you have forwarded the X).
To execute a DOS command prompt, just type "cmd.exe".
If you want the DOS command prompt to execute a bat file and exit, you can do it like this:

cmd.exe /C '"C:\Path\to\file 1.bat"' (The single quotes are due to as the name has spaces, the cmd parameters needs the double quotes, and to avoid Bash to take them out, we have to put them between single quotes).

Note: If you want a quick Cygwin installation, you can try this package: ["http://www.gage.es/glab-download"](http://www.gage.es/glab-download). This installation is from an open source program (gLAB), which already has an automatic Cygwin installation embedded. Just erase the gLAB later, and you will have a Cygwin with everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

It is a gaping security hole since it allows password-less connection to your Windows box from anywhere, but if you are only doing this at home inside a private network, it may be ok.

Basically, you would install the tiny program called `netcat` (also known as `nc`) on your Windows box. It is already installed on most Linux boxes.

Then on your Windows box, in a Command Prompt you tell `netcat` to listen on port 10000 (or any other one you choose) and run `cmd.exe` to process whatever it receives on that port:

```
nc -l -p 10000 -v -e cmd.exe
```

On your Linux box, you connect to port 10000 of your Windows box and then the commands you type in your Linux box are processed by `cmd.exe` on your Windows box. So, assuming your Windows box has the IP address 192.168.0.10:

```
nc 192.168.0.10 10000

process file.xls
```

Of course, installing an `ssh` server is more secure, but this approach has the advantage that it requires very little setup at all.

**Option 2**

Another option might be to share a directory between the Linux and Windows machine and have the Windows machine regularly (every 10 seconds maybe) check the directory for new files and if it sees any process them and then move them to a different directory called, say `Processed` so that they don't get processed again on the next iteration. So there would be a BATCH script running on Windows that just did a loop:

```
@echo off
:top
echo Checking for files...
FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (*.CSV) DO (
   process file
   move file to processed subdirectory
)
sleep 3
goto top
```

See [ss64 website](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for syntax of `FOR` loop.